# How long does it take to install Azure monitor agent using Data collection rule

Tags: azure, monitor, agent

How long does it take to install Azure monitor agent using Data collection rule.

Does it take minutes or hours or days?? How can I find out the state of the installation?? Is there a command for that??

I have tried to install Azure Monitor agent using Data Collection Rule.

It does not show in Log Analytics Workspace

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

yeah you can check this using PowerShell, lemme show you how

Open a PowerShell console with administrative privileges, If you haven't installed the Az module, you can install it using the following command and after that signing to your azure

```
Install-Module -Name Az -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser



Connect-AzAccount
```

Use the following command to check the installation status of the Azure Monitor agent

```
Get-AzDataCollectionRuleStatus -ResourceGroupName <YourResourceGroup> -WorkspaceName <YourWorkspaceName>
```

Replace  and  with your actual resource grup and workspace names.

Comment: If this helps you can accept the answer so that helps people with similar issue

Comment: This command does not exist any more Get-AzDataCollectionRuleStatus